# JavaFX choicebox text color

Tags: java, css, javafx

Iam trying to change the TextColor of an ChoiceBox in JavaFX.

This is my css file:

```
.choice-box{
      -fx-background-color: 
        #000000,
        linear-gradient(#7ebcea, #2f4b8f),
        linear-gradient(#426ab7, #263e75),
        linear-gradient(#395cab, #223768);
    -fx-padding: 3 10 4 20;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
}
```

And this is a screenshot of my choice-box:

[image]

`-fx-text-fill: white;` works on buttons but not on choic boxes. Why?

How can i change the color of the text in the choicebox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think you can do:

```
.choice-box .label {
     -fx-text-fill: white; 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, with a slight tweak: .choice-box > .label  See my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77039832/javafx-choicebox-prompt-text-color

Answer (score 1):

You should give these properties to the listcell and not the choice-box. Refer this : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled

Hope it helps