# JavaFX choicebox [combobox] Prompt Text Color

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-css

I am working on a project using JavaFX. I have a question about styling the choicebox control UI. I am new to JavaFX, so please be kind.

For the choicebox UI control, I changed the prompt background color, but kept the prompt text color, menu list text color, menu list background color, selected text color, and selected background color as the default. However, since the choicebox prompt background color is dark, I wanted to change the prompt text color to a shade of white, so that the text is readable. However, I cant seem to change the prompt text color to be white, without also changing the menu list text color to be white. Since the background color of the menu list is also white, when the choicebox menu list is displayed, you cant discern the white menu list text from the white menu list background. In other words, I want to change the prompt text color, but not the menu list text color. Is this possible?

I saw that css stylings are defined in the [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/IdelsTak/b0dcfa22b54365f2daa770ad54c3f9e7) file. However things Ive tried using this file as a reference didnt work.

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957272/javafx-choicebox-text-color) in my custom stylesheet.css, and it changes the prompt text, but also it changes the menu list text (which like I said I am trying to avoid).

stylesheet.css

```
.choice-box {
  -fx-background-color : #5F9EA0; /* Cadet Blue */
  -fx-text-fill : white;
  -fx-font-family : sans-serif;
  -fx-font-size : 12;
  -fx-font-style : normal;
}

.choice-box .label {
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Java code

```
// main screen
Scene scene1 = new Scene(gridRoot, 600, 600);
scene1.getStylesheets().add("stylesheet.css");
primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
primaryStage.show();
```

Without -fx-text-fill: white;

[image]
[image]

With -fx-text-fill: white;

[image]
[image]

Please advise.

EDIT: I ended up going with a combo-box / combobox / combo box, because it has scroll bars when the list exceeds a set length. I described how I achieve the combo-box styling here: [combo-box styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687960/javafx-css-changing-text-color-of-comboboxs-selected-item). To config it the way I wanted to, I had to set these options:

```
myComboBox.setVisibleRowCount(15);
myComboBox.setEditable(false);
```

Comment: I think I solved it. Instead of ".choice-box .label", it should be ".choice-box > .label"

Comment: Normally JavaFX solves these kind of issues in modena using a combination of [looked up colors, derivation and ladder functions](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor).  You can find examples in modena.css.  Sometimes if it you set the appropriate looked up color such as fx-base to a new value,  other derived colors will automatically adjust based on the ladder functions in modena.  Probably doesn’t matter in your case right now as you seem to have found a solution which works for you, but perhaps something to consider in the future: